# How to plug PCB into PLCC Socket

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I have an IC that I need to replace by a small PCB. IC is currently plugged in the 44-pin PLCC socket. Is there a way I can keep this socket in place? That is, can I somehow "plug" this new PCB (which I will use instead of IC) into the 44-pin PLCC socket?

PCB is not yet designed, so I have flexibility of adding various pins or adapters.

PLCC Socket looks something like this:
[image: PLCC socket looks something like this]

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be possible to integrate plcc pins into a pcb: [complete fpga development board that fits in a plcc socket](https://www2.hdl.co.jp/en/index.php?id=207)

Answer (score 8):

The answer seems to be "yes but it's gonna cost you".

A quick google for "PLCC test plug" turned up https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/plcc-sockets/2446896/

Comment: Yes, something like this I also found. I wondered if someone had experience with creating a PCB with pins that could fit this socket.